# Dynamically generate a Spark Column via doing a DB fetch operation

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a spark dataframe with 2 columns.

I want to generate a 3 rd column on the spark dataframe .

The 3rd column has to be populated by a value fetched from DB using the first 2 columns.

```
data = data.withColumn("z", getValueOfZ(col("x"),col("y")));
```

I am unable to figure out , how do I populate the value of y using x and y in the function `getValueOfZ()`.
The getValueOfZ() needs to execute a select query based on the values of x and y and return the value of Z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what `getValueOfY()`is supposed to do. You have 3 options with Spark.

## Simple operation

If it is a simple operation, you can use `expr()`. For example, if the result is a sum of x and y, you could use:

```
df = df.withColumn("y", expr("x + y")));
```

You can use `expr()` by:

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr;
```

## Built-in functions

Spark offers a lot of those functions. Their [Javadoc is available here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html).

## Custom UDF transformation

If your code is more complex and cannot be dealt through an expression or a function, you can call a UDF (user-defined function).

I hope it helps, do not hesitate to comment to ask more question.

Comment: I edited my query. I need to do a db fetch to populate the value

Comment: getValueOfZ() needs to access the database? In this case, you will have to write a UDF.

Comment: A rather clean option would be to fetch the data from database in a dataframe and derive that column using join. Calling database using UDF on each row wold be taxing for your database.

Comment: @kaysuch - I agree, you could indeed do that, it depends how much information there is in this lookup table.